# Entity Framework with Linq, inner join on subquery with includes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have 3 entities warehouse, bank and warehouse_bank. warehouse_bank is a many to many on the respective tables.

What i want to do is :-

```
        Expression<Func<Warehouse, bool>> expressionBuilder = w => w.Warehouse_Bank.Where(wb => wb.IdBank == idBank && wb.IsDeactivated !=true).Count() > 0 && w.IsDeactivated !=true;
```

In the above I wanted to get all warehouse and its associating warehouse_bank but with only warehouse_bank belonging to a particular idbank and also those warehouse_bank which IsDeactivated !=true;

Is this possible in one query ?

Comment: * you should list your model classes along with the expression you tried

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Include` to include the Warehouse in the query. Also I am not sure why you have `Count() > 0` since if the count is not bigger than 0, it will not show up in the results anyways. Here is the query:

```
w.Warehouse_Bank.Include(x => x.Warehouse)
    .Where(wb => wb.IdBank == idBank && wb.IsDeactivated !=true);
```

If you want to filter the `Warehouse`, do it like this:

```
w.Warehouse_Bank
   .Include(x => x.Warehouses.Where(y => y.Whatever == whatever))
   .Where(wb => wb.IdBank == idBank && wb.IsDeactivated != true);
```

Comment: I cannot add a function in include, i only can add string, is there an extension i need to import ?

Comment: Ok I found it, i had to include "System.Data.Entity", however now i'm getting "The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties" error on execution